# How to initialize PropertyChangeSupport when deserializing from JSON (Gson)?

Tags: java, gson, json-deserialization, propertychangesupport

I have my object implemented the `PropertyChangeSupport`, but when I deserialize from a json string, the variable `propertyChangeSupport` would be `null`, despite I initialize the value myself with a `new PropertyChangeSupport(this)` in the default constructor. How can I initialize or deserializing it properly using Gson?

Say I have this object:

```
public class Blah implements BlahInterface {
    private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;

    protected int id;
    protected BlahType type;

    public Blah() {
        propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BlahType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(BlahType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public PropertyChangeListener[] getPropertyChangeListeners() {
        return this.propertyChangeSupport.getPropertyChangeListeners();
    }
}
```

I also tried putting the `new PropertyChangeSupport(this);` directly at the beginning and is no go either. I kind a want to avoid manually making a function such as `initializePropertyChangeSupport()` and then call it manually after deserialization since that's kinda ugly.

What I'm trying to do:

```
JsonArray ja = json.get("blahs").getAsJsonArray();
ja.forEach(item -> {
    Blah blah = BlahInterface.Parse(item.toString());
    // But here I can't addPropertyChangeListener because propertyChangeSupport is null
    // vvvvvvvvvvvv
    blah.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            BlahState state = (BlahState) evt.getNewValue();
            Logger.debug("Property had been updated, " + state.toString());
        }
    });
});
```

This is my json parsing function:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Blah> T Parse(String json) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Blah t = new Blah(gson.fromJson(json, Blah.class));
    switch (t.getType()) {
        case blahone:
            return (T) gson.fromJson(json, BlahOne.class);
        default:
            return (T) t;
    }
};
```

Comment: Where do you fire the notification method anywhere?

Comment: Also how can you add a listener to an object before it exists? I'm not clear exactly **what** property the property change listeners will be listening to -- what is supposed to be the *bound* property(s) of this class? If it's the `id` property, then the setter method needs to call the support object's notification methods.

Comment: I add my `PropertyChangeListener` after I deserialize my json object, basically I get a json string from server, then with that data, I deserialize it into my `Blah` object, and then try to add the my `PropertyChangeListener` to it. The problem is that the variable is null since it wasn't part of the json string, but I am trying to avoid ugly hacks...

Comment: What variable is null? Please tell more details and show more pertinent code.

Comment: Are you saying that here: `Blah blah = BlahInterface.Parse(item.toString());`, the `blah` variable is `null`? Again, ***what*** is null? And again, where within Blah do you call the support's `firePropertyChange(...)` method?

Comment: `propertyChangeSupport`

Comment: You could inject the support object after JSON creation I suppose

Comment: or you could lazily create it in the `addPropertyChangeListener` method if it's null. By "lazy creation" -- only create the object if it's null. Otherwise use it.

Comment: So there is no harm of not using `final` on the `propertyChangeSupport`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html

Comment: ....don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to implements `InstanceCreator<T>` in my object. So that when Gson tries to deserialize the object, it would call the `createInstance` function which in turns returns a proper object with the `PropertyChangeSupport` variable initialized. Example code below:

```
public class Blah implements InstanceCreator<Blah> {
    private final transient PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    ...

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public Blah createInstance(Type type) {
        return new Blah();
    }   
}
```

Note: transient keyword is there on the `pcs` just so that Gson would skip it during serialize otherwise Gson would throw exception.